# Codesign error: 'the code has no main executable file'

Tags: ios, code-signing

I made a copy of a working, building, totally-super project to start working on a related project.

The new project **builds but won't code sign**. **The old project still builds and runs fine.** Simulator, Device, whatever. New project: Only simulator.

Here's the error:

```
/Developer/apps/myNewApp/build/myNewApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myNewApp.app: 
the code has no main executable file
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

`the code has no main executable file`? What? It does. Totally. I checked. And, it's the same `main.m` that is in the old project.

I didn't change machines or anything, just cloned the project locally with Git and changed the name. Changing an executable name can be dodgy in XCode/iOS, but I think I have that part sorted out.

I am using a wildcard provisioning ID, though, so I don't think the app name should matter. I have been looking for some hidden setting or something that's missing, cleaned, restarted, even deleted and reinstalled my certificates! Anybody seen this before? Have something for me to try?

Comment: Wait, did that just say main.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that some combination of restarting, switching the target from `debug` to `release` and debugger from GDB to 'none' and back... eventually fixed it.

The one thing I did that I hadn't seen other places was **remove an extra "Any SDK" setting in Build Settings, manually, by opening project.pbxproj in TextEdit** and deleting the appropriate line. (I couldn't remove it from within XCode.) So I had, under Debug, "Any SDK" and also "Any iOS SDK", which might have been related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`main.h` does not exist in conventional objective-c executables.  Rename it to `main.m` and run again.  No wonder it can't find your executable, it's a method file, not a header file!

Comment: Thanks, but that was actually a typo.

Comment: Right click on your .app file and reveal it in the finder.

Comment: I was just trying to see if it existed... There is honestly no reason for this to be happening... Make another project is all I can say...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I mistakenly had a space character at the end of the product name in the project build settings.